# Is the maximum sectional curvature smooth?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, smooth-functions

Given a smooth Riemannian manifold (M,g), is the function $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as the maximum of sectional curvatures at each point $m \in M$, smooth?

I think for each point $m \in M$, sectional curvature is a real valued function on the Grassmannian(2,d) where $d$ is the dimension of $M$. Since the Grassmannian is compact, maximum is achieved and $f$ can be defined.

I would like to learn more about the function $f$; thank you.

Comment: I think it's unlikely to be smooth, as taking maximums rarely is.

Comment: Is $R_p(X,Y,X,Y)$ jointly continuous (smooth) in $p$ and the vector fields $X,Y$?

Comment: At points of unique maximum $f$ will be smooth, otherwise, there is no reason for its smoothness, but constructing an example will be painful.